# Is there any Apache Spark counterpart similar to Hadoop Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have some highly customized processing logic that I want to implement in C++. [Hadoop Streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html) enables me to integrate the C++-coded logic into the MapReduce processing pipeline. I'm wondering whether I can do the same with Apache Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest (but not exactly the equivalent) solution, is [`RDD.pipe`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) method:

> Return an RDD created by piping elements to a forked external process. The resulting RDD is computed by executing the given process once per partition. All elements of each input partition are written to a process's stdin as lines of input separated by a newline. The resulting partition consists of the process's stdout output, with each line of stdout resulting in one element of the output partition. A process is invoked even for empty partitions.
>
> The print behavior can be customized by providing two functions.

Spark [test suite](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/2cfd41ac02193aaf121afcddcb6383f4d075ea1e/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PipedRDDSuite.scala#L39) provides a number of usage examples.

Comment: Yes, I think this will do :)